# how to extract pdf iin elasticsearch using java code

Tags: java, elasticsearch

like say Elasticsearch is backend code, java coding is front end coding.
My PDF file will save at Elasticsearch there. 
Now i need using java coding front end coding to extract the pdf file, then juz send index to elasticsearch backend
i will use java xml to connect with elasticsearch

```
private void readElasticSearchConfig() {

    String configparam = factoryType.serverXML.getAdapterConfigParams();

    if (configparam != null && configparam.length() > 0) {
        xmlepath = StringUtility.configParamsLookup("|", configparam, "NEWS_STORY_FOLDER");
        newssource = StringUtility.configParamsLookup("|", configparam, "news_source");
        indexserver = StringUtility.configParamsLookup("|", configparam, "indexserver");
        isInsertElasticSearchIndex = true;
        out.println("Read xmlpath = " + xmlepath + "->newssource :" + newssource + "->indexserver :" + indexserver);
    }

}
```

example at xml 
NEWS_STORY_FOLDER=D:/NEWS_ARCHIVE/Bursa/newsStory/|news_source=N|indexserver=http://127.0.0.1:9200/news/TRKD/

After that all data will insert into bean file.
the below is java front end coding

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import org.apache.tika.parser.pdf.PDFParser;
import org.apache.tika.metadata.Metadata;
import org.apache.tika.parser.ParseContext;
import org.apache.tika.sax.BodyContentHandler;
import org.xml.sax.ContentHandler;

public void generateJsonObject(NewsContentObj newsContentObj, String sNewsID) {
    try {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().disableHtmlEscaping().create();
        BodyContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler();
        Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
        File folder = new File("D:/workspace/AdapterReuters_TRKD_News/bin/test");
        String fileName = "D:\\workspace\\AdapterReuters_TRKD_News\\bin\\test\\Order Summary.pdf";
        FileInputStream inputstream = new FileInputStream(new File(fileName));
          ParseContext pcontext = new ParseContext();

          //parsing the document using PDF parser
          PDFParser pdfparser = new PDFParser(); 
          pdfparser.parse(inputstream, handler, metadata,pcontext);

          newsContentObj.setContent(handler.toString());
        out.println("contents test :" + newsContentObj.getContent());

        String Json = gson.toJson(newsContentObj);
        // out.println("String Builder  :" +sContent.toString());
        out.println("JSON :" + Json);

        sendIndexer(sNewsID, Json);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        out.println("News Id :" + sNewsID + " -> Exception :" + ex);
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void sendIndexer(String nid, String json) {
    try {
        String url = indexserver + nid;
        StringEntity reqEntity = new StringEntity(json, "application/json", "UTF8");

        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);

        post.setEntity(reqEntity);

        CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();

        CloseableHttpResponse res = httpclient.execute(post);

        // Issue to solve: if sleep is not applied,
        // JQC will be too quick to respond and call back ES causing blank data as ES had not finish index new data
        // below is just temp fix, most likely need migrate to use ES API to get actual push index success
        //Thread.sleep(5000);

        // Debug purpose
        // out.println("Send Indexer status: " + res.getStatusLine());

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
        out.println("Send Indexer encoding exception: This should not happen unless hardcoded item being changed!");
    } catch (ClientProtocolException cpe) {
        out.println("Send Indexer CPE exception: " + cpe);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        out.println("Send Indexer IO exception: " + ioe);
    }
}
```

First question:

1. how to connect input pdf file from elastic search using java coding?i need add anything at xml file?
2. After connect, how to extract pdf file? i have try using example at generate JsonObject, but it have failure "Exception in thread "Thread-25" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/PDDocument", what should i do?

Thanks

Comment: Add PDFBox and Fontbox to your project.

Answer (score 0):

I created a full project which does something similar: [FSCrawler](https://github.com/dadoonet/fscrawler).
The extraction logic is coded [here](https://github.com/dadoonet/fscrawler/blob/master/src/main/java/fr/pilato/elasticsearch/crawler/fs/tika/TikaDocParser.java).

I don't understand your questions though.

Comment: Thanks..Ignore my question first.. How you setting for fssetting, input stream? like public static void generate(FsSettings fsSettings, InputStream inputStream, String filename, Doc doc, MessageDigest messageDigest,
                                long filesize) throws IOException {

Comment: All the code is public. Just import it in your IDE and read it. There are also a lot of tests.

Answer (score 0):

You have four options:

- Ingest Attachment Plugin
- Apache Tika
- FsCrawler
- Ambar

I described pros and cons of every option in [this post](https://blog.ambar.cloud/ingesting-documents-pdf-word-txt-etc-into-elasticsearch/)